# How do I do the data restructure in SQL - from compact to expanded

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, plsql

I have an order table like below where all the orders associated with each group is listed in the same cell but separated by a comma ','. Now I'd like to expand the orders so that each order for each group is placed in different row. (The resulted table is below the original table).

Could you please tell me how to realize this in SQL?

Thanks a lot!

Here is the original compact table:

```
Group   Order
  1      ,a,b
  2      c,d,e
  3      f,g
  4      h
```

Here is the final expanded table:

```
Group  Order
  1     NULL
  1      a
  1      b
  2      c
  2      d
  2      e
  3      f
  3      g
  4      h
```

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... stuff like this (string manipulation) is very vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: Do you try my example ? Is it usefull for you ?

Comment: to marc_s, how about in Microsoft SQL Server 2008?

Comment: Hi TwTw, thank you for the input. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this , it works perfectly for me :

```
DECLARE @name_2 VARCHAR(MAX), @start INT, @flag bit, @id int ,@name nvarchar(max)

DECLARE c CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
FOR SELECT name,id FROM table_1;

open c;
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @name,@id;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN
   SET @flag = 1 
   SET @start = 0
   WHILE @start < LEN(@name) 
    BEGIN
      SET @start = @start + 1
      SET @name_2 =  SUBSTRING(@name, @start, 1) 
      if (@flag = 1 and @name_2 = ',')
          SET @name_2 = null 
      if(@name_2 <> ',' OR @name_2 is null)
        BEGIN   
           INSERT into dbo.Table_2 (id,name)
           values (@id,@name_2) 
        END
      SET @flag = 0   
    END
  FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @name,@id;
END

CLOSE c;
DEALLOCATE c;
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use regular expression, try this:

```
with temp  as (
     select 1 id, ',a,b' str from dual
     union all
     select 2, 'c,d,e' from dual
     union all
     select 3, 'f,g' from dual
     union all
     select 4, 'h' from dual    
)

SELECT distinct id, regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, level) str
FROM temp CONNECT BY instr(str, ',', 1, level - 1) > 0
order by 1, 2 nulls first
```